# Slick grid is not working for more than 8 rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, slickgrid, slick

In our  MVC  application ,we are using slick grid for displaying a data for Update,We are passing a json string to grid and display the rows for update .But until 8 rows it's working fine.but more than 8 rows Update is not working.While Update we are passing the json string to the controller and save the changes in the table. but When i checked in Firefox firbug the following error is coming .
**TypeError: grid.base is undefined**

My sample code: (for Displaying)
            **grid = new Slick.Grid($("#grid-dplistitem"), data, columns, options);**
            **grid.base.render();**

For update

```
      grid.getEditController().commitCurrentEdit();
        var data = grid.getData();
        var griddata = JSON.stringify(data);


        $.ajax({

            url: '/Project/UpdateProjectMessage?gridData=' + griddata,
            //data: "gridData=" + JSON.stringify(data),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json',
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help you 
add the following code in your web config file

```
<system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
```